# name "n_fft" not defined

Tags: python, audio

so I'm currently working on an audio classification ai in Python, for recognizing sounds out of a dataset that I created. This is the second week I'm working with python so I'm a bit iffy on the exacts, though I am familiar with C++. Anyways, I get this error in my code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [83], in <cell line: 3>()
      5 else:
      6                 wav=wav[:5*sr]
----> 7                 spec=librosa.feature.melspectrogram(wav, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft),
      8                 hop_length=hop_length,n_mels=n_mels,fmin=fmin,fmax=fmax
      9                 spec_db=librosa.power_to_db(spec,top_db=top_db)

NameError: name 'n_fft' is not defined
```

And this is my code block in Jypter notebook:

```
def get_melspectrogram(file_path, sr=None, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, n_mels=128, fmin=20, fmax=8300, top_db=80):
      wav,sr = librosa.load(file_path,sr=sr)
if wav.shape[0]<5*sr:
            wav=np.pad(wav,int(np.ceil((5*sr-wav.shape[0])/2)),mode='reflect')
else:
                wav=wav[:5*sr]
                spec=librosa.feature.melspectrogram(wav, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft),
                hop_length=hop_length,n_mels=n_mels,fmin=fmin,fmax=fmax
                spec_db=librosa.power_to_db(spec,top_db=top_db)
return spec_db
```

So what would be the problem here? I defined n_fft as 2048 in the function get_melspectrogram. Would I have to use a global? Might be simple, but again I'm a little new to python and I wanted to pick up a project with my friends who are also writing in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is one function although indenting is not shown. To resolve the error instead of melspectrogram(wav, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft) just use melspectrogram(wav, sr, n_fft) instead.

Comment: Yeah its one function out of many. Also, thanks, that seemed to resolve the issue I'll probably read up on indentation in the documentation.